# Sort a vector using its elements

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, stdvector

i need to know how can we sort a vector of user define class using its elements.
Say i have a class called "coordinates" with getX and getY method that return an int value.
I have created and array of vector "vector PointTwoD vcP2D(5);"

```
 class coordinates {
 int getX();
 int getY();

  )
```

Now the issue, 
1)  I need to sort the vector "vcP2D" using getX() and sort in asc order
2)  Say an user enters the "2" as the x coordinate. And using that info i need to find which vector contains 2

Please advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const coordinates& c, const coordinates& d){ return c.getX() < d.getX(); });
```

It uses a C++11 Lambda expression as a binary predicate for `std::sort`.

A short [demonstration](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e4ab5f38881fa180e9ed19027a57370a):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

struct coordinates
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<coordinates> v{ {2,3}, {0,0}, {1,5} };

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const coordinates& c, const coordinates& d) { return c.x < d.x; });

  std::cout << "sorted by x values, values of \"x\": " << v[0].x << " " << v[1].x << " " << v[2].x << "\n";

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const coordinates& c, const coordinates& d) { return c.y < d.y; });

  std::cout << "sorted by y values, values of \"x\": "  << v[0].x << " " << v[1].x << " " << v[2].x << "\n";
}
```

---

A [demo of how to find an element](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cbcdb37f9dea92c0c86155c4b0acff72) in the same way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

struct coordinates
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<coordinates> v{ {2,3}, {0,0}, {1,5} };

  auto result = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const coordinates& c){ return c.x == 1 && c.y == 5; });
  if(result != v.end())
    std::cout << "point (1,5) is number " << std::distance(v.begin(), result)+1 << " in the vector.\n";
  else
    std::cout << "point (1,5) not found.\n";
 }
```

If you are looking to search in the sorted vector, you can use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) which takes a comparison function (the same as `std::sort` above). It also does not give an iterator to that element, only a `true` or `false`.

Comment: A demonstration on finding would be nice too. Not sure if searching the sorted or unsorted data is what the OP wants though.

Comment: @LucDanton Done. He can find the `std::binary_search` code on his own I think `:)`

Comment: I'd recommend 'lower_bound' over 'binary_search'.  'binary_search' is rarely helpful, and I don't think it should have been in the STL.

Comment: @rubenvb i cant access the elements in the vector. vector has a method "getX.()" which returns a int and i cant acess this value, thus i am not able to compare.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a strict weak order on your elements, either using `operator< ()` or a binary predicate, and then use `std::sort()`.

The easiest approach is to create a less than `operator<()`:

```
bool operator< (coordinates const& c0, coordinates const& c1) {
    // return a suitable result of comparing c0 and c1 such that operator<()
    // become a strict weak order
}
```

With this all you need to do to sort a `std::vector<coordinates>` is to use `std::sort()`. To locate a specific object you would use `std::lower_bound()`.

Comment: @KenBloom sorry i dont understand. I am new to vector and c++ please advise more clearly

Comment: i still dont get it can you explain we some running codes. I am still learning how to use vector and stuffs. Still a student so i not good with just convections